# Remove all letters between two underscores with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My directory has a list of filenames similar to `_3vaca3424434_1-lecture-introduction.pdf` and I want to rename it as `1-lecture-introduction.pdf`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for f in *; do
    new_f=${f##_*_}
    echo mv -- "$f" "$new_f"
done
```

Review the output of the above, and if the commands look right, remove the `echo` and run again.

`${f##_*_}` removes the longest prefix matching the pattern `_*_` from the value of `$f`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner! What does the `--` after `mv` mean?

Comment: Just a precaution. Let's say you had a file named `-i`. Without the `--`, it would be treated as an option to`mv`. With it, anything following it is treated strictly as an argument, not an option. Most likely, you don't need it, but it won't hurt.